# "Duplicate object name" in LUIS Programmatic API

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am trying to use LUIS Programmatic API in order to create a LUIS app.

The response I get is:

```
"error": {
  "code": "BadArgument",
  "message": "Duplicate object name"
}
```

The app contains intents, utterances and several Closed Lists.

I checked that there are no utterances and no duplicate entries in closed lists, but that didn't help.

What else could cause the problem? Normally, with some other data, I was able to create the LUIS app using the same code successfully.

Comment: Can you post the app you are trying to publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be two entity synonyms that had different value (different, but similar Chinese characters) that for some reason were treated as the same character by LUIS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2 or more methods in your Luis dialog that have the same intent mapped to it?

Make sure that your intents are mapped correctly. I think if you have a typo in your intent, that may map to none.